# How do I do a minimal install without an internet connection?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-minimal

Now that various Ubuntu ISOs has been folded into the regular desktop ISO, how do I install the minimal version which featured in the erstwhile alternate and the minimal ISO?

**Minimal CD**

Regarding minimal CD, it can install minimal Ubuntu  but requires net connection to download even the basic that basic set of Ubuntu packages. And therein lies the problem: I don't have a LAN connection I can use and, even if text-based installers did support wireless connections (they don't, IME), my wireless hardware is a little too new and requires manually compiling and installing drivers.

If you do have net connection and want to install minimal Ubuntu, [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) is the way to go.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Install minimal Ubuntu from Ubuntu Server 12.10 USB/DVD

You can achieve a 12.10 minimal (no GUI) install via the Ubuntu Server installer image downloadable from the [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) page or the [alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) page.

The minimal install option has been made available via different modes as detailed on the following screen shots.

- **Opt to install a minimal system**

[image: Choose minimal system installation mode]
Press F4, and you will be able to choose minimal system installation mode.

- **Skip or choose manual package selection**

[image: Skip this step without selecting anything]
Going further, you will eventually be asked if you want to install more packages on top of the minimal system. If you want a pure command-line system, skip the step without choosing anything. Or you can select the last "Manual package selection" option to preemptively select any packages you were planning to install to build your custom environment.

[image: Manual package selection using Aptitude]
Upon choosing manual package selection, you will be greeted by a standard interactive instance of [Aptitude](http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude) if you chose manual package selection. If you're unfamilar with operating Aptitude, refer to [this guide](http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude#Interactive_Use) to navigate and select packages. Do note that the selection of packages you will find are only those available on your installation media; an internet connection will be needed to install anything else at install time.

---

**Server Minimal vs Minimal CD**

While the minimal system installed using the Ubuntu Server image is undoubtedly a genuine minimal system as known and loved by minimalist lovers, there is a slight differences in the package package selection compared to the Minimal CD. In fact, Minimal CD pulls in 7 extra packages during installation, which I (@Oxwivi) personally deem them to be all but redundant. But for the information freaks (like myself) who will have nagging doubts if the details are not known,  the seven in question are: [`daemon`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/daemon), [`dictionaries-common`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/dictionaries-common), [`discover`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/discover), [`discover-data`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/discover-data), [`language-pack-gnome-en`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/language-pack-gnome-en), [`language-pack-gnome-en-base`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/language-pack-gnome-en-base), [`libdiscover2`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libdiscover2), [`mpt-status`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/mpt-status), [`wamerican`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/wamerican) and [`wbritish`](http://www.packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/wbritish).

Using the Lubuntu Alternate Installer, as this answer originally suggested, also worked and resulted in the same package list as installing Ubuntu Server. To use the Lubuntu Alternate Installer, minimal system mode must be chosen the same way as Ubuntu Server by pressing F4.

Comment: Hey, this does not apply as of 14.04; requires Internet connection even after choosing minimal. Any thoughts?

Comment: Scratch that. For some reason, it didn't ask me for internet connection last time I tried. But every other time since 14.04's release it wouldn't let me do anything without. I don't get it.

Comment: Excellent write-up! -- The links to the seven extra packages are now out of date.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly it's gone:

> The alternate installer, required when users want to configure
>   cryptsetup, Logical Volume Manager (LVM) or software-based RAID arrays
>   during installation, may disappear from Ubuntu as early as version
>   12.10. The idea is mooted in a proposal put forward by Steve Langasek, Engineering Manager at Canonical's Ubuntu Foundation.
>
> According to Langasek, dropping the alternate installer image would
>   represent a step towards reducing the number of Ubuntu installation
>   images. The guided partitioner in ubiquity – the installer from the
>   desktop live images – now contains extensions to set up cryptsetup for
>   encrypting whole disks and to manage disks using logical volume
>   manager. Both functions should, according to Langasek, also be
>   available with manual partitioning soon. The changes are planned for
>   Ubuntu 12.10, which is currently under development and due to be
>   released in October.
>
> The ability to set up software-based RAID arrays using mdadm will not,
>   however, be finished in time and ubiquity is unlikely to support this
>   before Ubuntu 13.04. Langasek nevertheless proposes dropping the
>   alternate installer in 12.10. Users who want to use RAID can continue
>   to use Ubuntu 12.04 or, alternatively, install 12.10 as normal, set up
>   a software-based RAID array manually and migrate their data to it. The
>   decision will only affect Ubuntu proper – Ubuntu variants such as
>   Kubuntu will continue to offer the option of creating images using the
>   alternate installer, which will continue to use a Debian
>   installer-based installation program.

[Source](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Ubuntu-to-drop-alternate-installer-1676906.html)

Comment: I know the alternate installer is gone, but are the features I seek are gone as well?

Comment: Well, what's your goal exactly?

Comment: Install a minimal, command line Ubuntu as I mention in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the [server version](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Ubuntu-to-drop-alternate-installer-1676906.html) of Ubuntu?

Comment: The server version is *similar*, but not the same. The minimal Ubuntu used all the desktop packages as opposed to the server-optimized binaries like the kernel.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm not sure about the specifics, but as far as I know Ubuntu Server had some modification in-kernel and other packages. It looks like it has changed since; can you link to relevant documentation articles?

Comment: @Oxwivi For information about how the server and desktop versions have *the same kernel* since 12.04, see [this section of the Server FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F) (list item 3), and also [this kernel-team mailing list message](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2011-October/017471.html).

Answer (score 3):

I think that for your minimal command line requirement, Ubuntu Core would suffice.

> Ubuntu Core is a minimal rootfs for use in the creation of custom
>   images for specific needs. Ubuntu Core strives to create a suitable
>   minimal environment for use in Board Support Packages, constrained or
>   integrated environments, or as the basis for application demonstration
>   images. It is available for the i386, amd64, and arm architectures.
>
> Ubuntu Core delivers a functional user-space environment, with full
>   support for installation of additional software from the Ubuntu
>   repositories, through the use of the `apt-get` command. —

[Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core)

Download: [From here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/)

Comment: I know about Ubuntu Core. But you do realize this is anything but an installer, right? Though I suppose I am going to go for this if I can't have any proper installers.

Comment: Yes, i understand that it has only the bare minimum. All things needed has to be installed. but it still has got the command-line interface you asked for. So thought that this might help you.

Comment: Looking at it from the perspective of a user who does not have a detailed knowledge of Ubuntu Core or how Linux systems work, this solution would be anything but an answer. Ubuntu Core carries a minimal system minus the crucial piece: the kernel. It is meant for devices like in-car systems where very specialized set-ups is required. After installing Ubuntu Core (which is essentially copying an entire root directory), you won't be able to use it. You'd need to `chroot` into Ubuntu Core, install the necessary kernel and related packages and then get the desired command line system.

Comment: @Oxwivi, Regarding the information in the last comment, I have to say that I wasn't aware of that. Really sorry and also thanks for this information. Should I remove this answer?

Comment: No, if, by the end of bounty, I do not get a better answer, I will choose this and edit it with the necessary info on getting Ubuntu Core running as a minimal command line system.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is more for the admin user, wanting to create an install CD. If you are just a desktop user and want to install Ubuntu this is probably overkill.

Check out Debian Live (Yes for Ubuntu!). Afaik. Ubuntu provides the live-build package (or similiar) from the Debian project which can also create Ubuntu live CDs. You can include an installer and packages with this CD. The entire process of building the live system is quite easy.

Create a directory "live", then `cd live`, Create a directry auto and a file "auto/config" with exec permissions. The file should look like this:

```
lb config noauto \
     --apt-source-archives false \
     --architectures i386 \
     --binary-images iso-hybrid \
     --debian-installer live \
     --debian-installer-distribution quantal \
     --debian-installer-gui true \
     --distribution quantal \
     --mode ubuntu \
     --system live \
     --win32-loader true \
     --package-lists ubuntu-cloud-desktop \
     "${@}"
```

See the manual here: http://live.debian.net/manual/html/live-manual.en.html

Then run `lb config` and `sudo lb build`. Voila, there you get an image for CDs or USB sticks with a complete installer.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

As stated [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation), this will not work because Ubiquity ignores some preseed components, like `tasksel` because "(...) they do not fit with Ubiquity's mode of operation".

---

I'm assuming what you are asking is a way to install the Ubuntu Desktop without the "desktop".

If you are using a USB device to install Ubuntu you can try to change the file `pressed/ubuntu.seed` present in your USB disk, replacing

```
tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect ubuntu-desktop
```

with

```
tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect standard
```

I haven't tested it, but it should create a basic Ubuntu installation without the "desktop".

Also, i've read somewhere that the only differences between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server are at the kernel used and the IO scheduler (if someone could prove or deny this would be nice). If this is true you can just use a Ubuntu Server CD and after the installation install the "desktop" kernel and alter the IO scheduler.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure that it's that easy? Cause if it is, it'd be *absolutely* awesome. Damn if only I could use a virtual system to try.

Comment: Refer to this [comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203122/how-do-i-do-a-minimal-install-without-an-internet-connection/207241#comment258201_207241) on the answer @fossfreedom provided; this doesn't work. :(

Comment: It seems that [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation) ignores those intructions. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

There are two Alternative iso images to my understanding the network installers and the full image which you can get here [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) you will need a bit torrent client to download the full iso which does not require a network connection

when installing it will auto try to setup a network connection it will fail as you are not connected to the internet it will then go to  a screen where there will be a few options one saying to try again or to go the menu select to go to the menu and then select the next logical step in the setup i have tried this personally and it works to my best knowledge

Comment: I think you are missing the whole point of a *minimal* install.

Comment: you can do a minimal install with the full alternative iso you chose it before you start to install and theres still no need for an internet connection like i said i did this before on my computer

Comment: Oh, I thought you've seen the Alternative Downloads page you linked before posting an answer. Please read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/203131). There is no Alternate CDs starting from Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: are you saying that there will not be any alternative installer after 12.10?

Comment: Forget *after*, 12.10 itself has no alternative installers other than the Ubuntu Server flavor.

Comment: there are alternative installers for 12.10 but its network so yea i see that now

Answer (score 1):

I think you are stuck with the Precise images for the alternate installer.  This is a shame, in my opinion, as it removes Ubuntu one step further from power users like yourself.

Now, after installing Precise from the CD, you will be, well, running an older version.  My recommended course of action at this point would be to make a custom Quantal repo DVD and apt-get dist-upgrade from it.  [Here is a nice tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352460) about making repo DVDs.

This approach has several problems, namely that you still have to download a ton of data.  Second, I think Ubuntu frowns upon dist-upgrade as an update method; they have a special tool that does the update, so you'd have to download it and run it manually, assuming you could even make it use local repos...

In other words, Canonical has decided you're out of luck.  I hate it, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I understand your need.

You need that the installed ubuntu can be used for your compilation needs without having to use internet. Plus you need a minimal operating system installed.

If it's the case I recommend you the full DVD sets of Debian testing. http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/

With those you'll be able to use your system being completely disconnected.

The DVDs contains all languages, binary and sources that debian officialy has. (so it contains the kernel sources, the compilations tools, etc).

I don't know about a ubuntu or ubuntu like that can do that much offline. Before you had alternative ISO of ubuntu ....

You can try with alternative ISO of Xubuntu or Lubuntu but I can't assure you that they'll have the sources (so you'll have to download them before). http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.04/release/

Best regards,

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not quite what you're looking for but worth mentioning:

What about [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall)?

This gives some handy files and ideas.

Comment: That doesnt solve his problem. Why should that be worth to mention?

Comment: This does not solve the solution indeed. If you're not going to answer the question, it's better to post a comment. And yes, I do know Lubuntu; I even had a *minimal* install Lubuntu. Even with the limited set of preinstalled apps, there are quite a few I don't use. Every byte mattered in the system with 4 GB HDD-though that's not the system in question this time.

Comment: Sorry guys, i shall place these as comments in future. I knew that it didn't specifically answer your question but could have been a step towards the solution, and hopefully this community could have built off it. but i see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is Minimal CD project:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Quantal images:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Minimal CD boots to minimal CLI system where you're supposed to use tasksel to install what your want.

Comment: Please refer to the comments on question. The *minimal* in minimal CD is referring to the size of the ISO, not what it will install. I can select the minimal set of packages to install, but it will need an internet connection which I cannot provide at install time.